# Creating A Class/Def For A If Else Statement Python

Tags: python, function, class, if-statement, methods

so I'm making a simple python program to ask maths questions. It is currently fully working but I want to try and condense the code down. The user has an option of 6 menu items to pick from, each one of these is an Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication..... And each one of them has the following code at the end to check if the user wants to carry on or try a different menu item.

```
contC = input()
        if contC == "Y" or contC == "y":
            cont = True

        elif contC == "N" or contC =="n":
            cont = False
```

This code is being in every menu choice, I want to create one method to be able to use for all of them, a class or a def? I've tried different things but can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Update your post with what you tried and how it failed. While you're editing remove the tag "Python" from the title, and get rid of the uppercases. Don't start a sentence with "so"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
def AskMethod(Operation):
   while True:
       print("Do you want to do " + Operation.name)
       Answer = input()
       if Answer.lower() in 'yes':
           Operation.use()  # Or return Operation. However you do it
           return False
       elif Answer.lower() in 'no':
           return True
       else:
           print("Please choose yes or no.")

for i in Ops:
    Continue = Ask(i)
    if Continue == False:
        break
```

To use this, you will need to make an op class, and an `ops` array containing all of the operations you want. You must add `self.name` and `self.use`  as well. Hope I helped.

Comment: Never test if something equals `False` by using `==`. You should always use `is`: i.e. `Continue is False:`. Where do you define the function `Ask()`?

Comment: If you type in 'o' at the input, you `AskMethod()` will return `True`, and similar if you type `e` or `s` it will return `False`.

Comment: @Anthon Why should they use an identity test on a boolean? The more right answer here would have been `if not Continue: ...`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Why should you not? There is only one object `False`.  And in general `if not Continue:` is not the same as `if Continue is False:`. Since we cannot know which values `Continue` can have since `Ask()` is not defined you cannot substitute that and be sure you don't change the logic/execution path taken (e.g. `Ask()` might return `[]` the empty list)

Comment: @Anthon If know `Continue` is a bool, then `is` is about the same as `==`, but then you wouldn't even need any of the two. Why create another bool with `Continue is False` when the object `Continue` itself is already a bool.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye A) You don't know that `Continue` is a bool, because you don't know what `Ask()` does, given this answer. B) if you ever run your code through `pep8` or `flake8` then `x == False` will throw an error E712, if you don't care about such tools, then of course you're not affected.

Comment: @Anthon I was never in support of `==`. I am of the opinion that a `is` is no better. It creates a new boolean, when the object itself can be used in the test. All Python objects are either truthy or falsy, so it holds even when `Continue` is not a bool. Therefore, I don't see why you need to justify the use of `is` with a style checker.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Not every "falsy" object in Python is the same and sometimes you need to follow different paths depending on `if x is None:` and `elif x is False:`. Your proposed `if not x` just cannot catch the difference. If you can't see that maybe you should post a question here on [so] as a new post, instead of having the question hiding in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a method

```
def should_continue(user_input):
    if user_input in ('y', 'Y'):
        return True
    if user_input in ('n', 'N'):
        return False
   raise ValueError("please enter y/n")
```

and then just

```
user_text = input()
cont = should_continue(user_input)
```

Comment: That is not a method, that is a function.

Comment: `continue` is a reserved keyword. You cannot use it for function names